# Slow rendering of pages due to User Controls

Tags: asp.net, performance

How would you troubleshoot a page that is rendering slowly in ASP.NET?

This issue is happening on only specific pages with a few user controls. Other pages work fine. Tracing has clarified that the issue is happening between "Begin Render" and "End Render".

Comment: Can you post the code between Begin Render and End Render?

Comment: Hi Rick... 

This question is more like a general approach for troubleshooting. I will answer this separately.

Comment: @Rahul: This isn't exactly the right way to get rep points.  Asking a general question, then pointing people to a blog post *you* wrote several months ago for the answer.  Yes, it's a good answer, but seriously just provide it when someone else asks.  Thanks

Comment: @Chris... first up, I am new to this SO and really keen on getting the things right. Here is what the FAQ says...

It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.

My intention was to just share the knowledge, because not many people do it the way I suggested in my answer even though it is a good way to get to the root cause. Rep points will come sooner or later.

Comment: @Rahul: After reading some of the responses on Meta about this very thing, I've come to the conclusion I was wrong. I'll change my down vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your responses! Check this link out... IMHO, this could be a way in fixing the issue permanently.

http://attosol.com/slow-page-rendering/

HTH

Comment: the http://attosol.com/slow-page-rendering/ link is broken as of Feb 18, 2017. Could you update the link or re-enable that content on your web site?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding [caching to your user controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx) or do they have to be permanently dynamic?

**EDIT**

If the render is causing pain then it suggests that you have heavy controls loading.

You could try to load the pages without the controls and then use ajax to pull in the heavy controls after the page has loaded - using the appropriate loading graphics.  [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) could be used to asynchronously load the heavier controls whilst allowing the user to see the page very quickly.

**EDIT**

Comment: The data is permanently dynamic. Besides, it will still have that initial "slowness" and the question here is to find out a detailed output about the "slow" control.

Comment: @Rahul Use ajax to asynchronously pull in the heavier controls.

Comment: @amelvin, although AJAX could make the appearance of the page "faster", inherently it wouldn't be faster. I will post the answer separately.

Comment: Sorry amelvin. I had to downvote, because using AJAX to pull the heavier controls is not really a resolution. It is just a workaround and it doesn't really tell you about the culprit control. Right? Please check my answer.  http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/How-to-troubleshoot-issues-with-Page-Rendering-in-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: @Rahul http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16236/when-should-correct-answers-get-downvoted

Comment: @amelvin... Ahh... am sorry man... I am a new user of SO and wasn't aware of this. I sincerely thank you for redirecting me to the link. I wanted to undo that downvote, but it wouldn't allow me to, unless you edit (I am guessing... the error message is... "Vote too old to be changed, unless this answer is edited".

If you edit, I think I can undo the vote.

Comment: @Rahul No worries. The http://meta.stackoverflow.com is packed with thoughts on etiquette and how to use the site - worth a browse.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [.Net Profiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools#.NET).

It's the only conclusive way to pinpoint your performance issues.